# Display the items in a list on an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have written a matching algorithm and the students who do not get matched, for whatsoever reason, are stored in a list in the Global Variable. I was this list to be sent to the admin as an email. I need help with reading the items from the list and adding them to the email.

the Global variable is:

```
public static List<string> V_result_rest_student = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> result_rest_student
        {
            get { return V_result_rest_student; }
            set { V_result_rest_student = value; }
        }
```

The function that calls the email service:

```
if(General.result_rest_student.Count > 0)
            {
               _emailService.SendStatusEMail(General.result_rest_student, User, EmailType.Unsorted_Students);
            }
```

The Program to send an email:

```
public void SendStatusEMail(List<string> list, User User, EmailType type)
        {

            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(config.mailSender, "Matching-Team");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("matching@gmail.com");

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            mail.Bcc.Add(from);

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = port;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            string header = string.Format(config.header);
            string footer = config.footer;

            if (list == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string msg = "";

            switch (type)
            {
                case EmailType.Unsorted_Student:
                    foreach (var item in list)
                    {
                        msg = item;

                    }
                    break;

                case EmailType.Finished_List:
                    msg = config.Finished_List;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            msg = string.Format(msg); 

            mail.Subject = string.Format(config.mailSubject, "List of Unsorted Students");
            mail.Body = header + msg + footer;


            try
            {
                client.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<Error> EMail Couldn't be sent.",
                            ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

I need the the UserId of the unsorted students to go to the admin as an email. I am using C#(.Net framework)

Comment: At this point you can do little to get the ID of your students. If the names are uniques (not very plausible) you can query the database to get back the ID from the name. The real solution is to build a List<Student> instead of a List<string> (or at least a list of a new class where you store only the Name and the ID). Then you have your ID for each student

Comment: Could you please show me that in code?

Comment: How do you prepare the list<string> that you are actually trying to use? That's the point where you need to prepare a different kind of list. Please show that code.

Answer (score 1):

i think you just need to add a var that turns your list into a string. Try this:

```
var result = String.Join("</BR>", General.result_rest_student);
```

The "`</BR>`" can be substituted for a ", " if you'd like everything to be on one line.

Comment: Should this go under the foreach loop in the place of msg?

Comment: you shouldnt have to. try var result = String.Join("</BR>", General.result_rest_student); and then the body of your message msg = result.ToString();